# Typescript type definition can occur x amount of times in another type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

So this is really hard to describe without code so let me show this first:

```
type SpacingMultiplier = 0 | 0.5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8;
type SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber = `${SpacingMultiplier}` | SpacingMultiplier;
type MultiValueSpacingMultiplier =
  | `${SpacingMultiplier} ${SpacingMultiplier} ${SpacingMultiplier} ${SpacingMultiplier}`
  | `${SpacingMultiplier} ${SpacingMultiplier} ${SpacingMultiplier}`
  | `${SpacingMultiplier} ${SpacingMultiplier}`
  | SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;

export interface Spacing {
  padding?: MultiValueSpacingMultiplier;
  paddingTop?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  paddingBottom?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  paddingLeft?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  paddingRight?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  margin?: MultiValueSpacingMultiplier;
  marginTop?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  marginBottom?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  marginLeft?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
  marginRight?: SpacingMultiplierStringOrNumber;
}
```

So as you can see, this is really ugly and unreadable. We are trying to create a spacing component in which it's possible to have `margin` and `padding` passed as props (or the individual CSS properties like `paddingLeft` and `marginBottom`). Now `padding` could take a number or string from the SpacingMultiplier (it'll multiply it by `0.25rem` since we're using a 4px grid) up to a total of 4 arguments (top, right, bottom, left). Is there any better way to write this like in regex you could with `{4}` or something?

We first define the `SpacingMultiplier` type. Then we define that this `SpacingMultiplier` can be either a `string` or a `number` and then we define that it could take up to 4 arguments (in case of defining `padding` or `margin`). But the way we're doing this now is, in my opinion, ugly and unreadable.

Is there any better and more readable way to properly do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpg5MN) meet your needs? There's nothing built in but you could write your own utility type.  Let me know if you want me to write that up as an answer, or if I'm missing something.

Comment: And also `Partial<Record<"padding" | ..., MultiValueSpacingMultiplier>>` if the interface is a problem too.